# Custom Transaction synchronization

Tags: spring-integration

Refering to the answer of Mr. Artem, who I thank very much:

"The simplest way to achieve that make channel for that `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>` as publish-subscribe and add one more  `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>`  to it.

This second subscriber will be invoked only when the first one has finished its work. And in this case the same Message will be sent to the DB adapter.

Another option is based on the `<request-handler-advice-chain>` together with `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, when you can specify the `onSuccessExpression` together with successChannel to send something to another channel on good result of adapter handling"

I woud like first of all to know for the first solution whether ^the usage of another type of subscriber such as a simple service activator or maybe `<int-mongo:outbound-channel-adapter>` are also guaranteed to be invoked ONLY after the successful accomplishement of the  `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>` request?

Second for the  `<request-handler-advice-chain>` how would I get the payload of the message in order to log it in my database? Do you have an example using `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` has an attribute `ignore-failures` which is `false` by default. The second subscriber will only be invoked if the first throws an exception if it is changed to `true`. To be sure of the invocation order, add `order="1"` to the first and `order="2"` to the second subscriber.
2. The advice has access to the original payload. See the [retry and more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) for an example of using the advice.

Comment: Hello Gary, thank you very much for your answer, very useful, but I am wondering if I shouldn't keep it false, so that if there's an `exception` raised by any of the `handlers` it will not invoke the second one ? Please correct me If I didn't understand well? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course you should set it to false (or leave it to default), I was just explaining how the channel works; I fixed the wording.